# add suffix to column name based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, rename

i want to add the prefix '_nan' to columns that are all nan. I have the following code that prints what I want but does not reassign the columns in the actual dataframe and I am not sure why. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a':[1, 0, 0, 0],
                    'b':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'c':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

```
a = df.loc[:,df.isna().all()].columns

df[[*a]] = df[[*a]].add_suffix('_nan')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [x + '_nan' if df[x].isna().all() else x for x in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
    a   b_nan   c_nan
0   1     NaN     NaN
1   0     NaN     NaN
2   0     NaN     NaN
3   0     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

*why this is happening?*

After some experiments I found that when you assign `pandas.DataFrame` slice to slice of `pandas.DataFrame` then `pandas` apparently does bother solely about order of columns (given in `list`), not their names, consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[10,20,30],'y':[400,500,600]})
df_1[['a','b']] = df_2[['x','y']]
print(df_1)
```

output

```
    a    b  c
0  10  400  7
1  20  500  8
2  30  600  9
```

whilst

```
...
df_1[['a','b']] = df_2[['y','x']]
print(df_1)
```

produce

```
     a   b  c
0  400  10  7
1  500  20  8
2  600  30  9
```